# How unique is the ethernet network adapter ID in WinRT? It is derived from the Mac address?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

How unique is the ethernet network adapter ID in WinRT? It is derived from the Mac address?

```
IReadOnlyCollection<Windows.Networking.Connectivity.ConnectionProfile> profiles =            Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles();

Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkAdapter na = profiles.First<Windows.Networking.Connectivity.ConnectionProfile>().NetworkAdapter;

string nid =  na.NetworkAdapterId.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the [NetworkAdapterId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkadapter.networkadapterid.aspx) value is a GUID and has nothing to do with the machine MAC address. You cannot get the MAC adress of the computer through WinRT APIs exposed for the Windows Store application type.

Comment: How is being a GUID related to being not unique (or pseudo unique)? On a phone/tablet, it isn't easy to replace the network adapter